# Can a UA Lore Mastery wizard use the Spell Secrets or Alchemical Casting features to modify spells cast through wands or staffs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, unearthed-arcana

My friends and I are playing D&D 5e. Our DM has allowed me to use the Arcane Tradition of Lore Mastery from [Unearthed Arcana: Warlock & Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf). I have a question regarding its Spell Secrets and Alchemical Casting features used in conjunction with spells cast from Wands or Staffs.

It has been confirmed by Jeremy Crawford himself that [if an item's description says that you cast a spell from it, then you can apply metamagic to that spell](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/714690060734631936).

My question is whether this applies to the abilities of the Lore Master wizard as well.
**Can a Lore Mastery wizard use Spell Secrets or Alchemical Casting to modify spells cast through wands or staffs?**

I'm specifically wondering about the *wand of lightning bolts* and *wand of fireballs*. I'm trying to see if I can use my abilities as a Lore Mastery wizard to change the damage types of the spells I am casting from these wands.

Comment: What kinds of Wands and Staff would you be using?

Comment: Wand of lightningbolt and fireballs. Evocation types. Im trying to see if i can use my abilities as a lore master to change the elements of thr spells i am casting from these wands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Lore Master's abilities don't work with spells cast from items

Unfortunately, the [Lore Master's](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf) **Spell Secrets** and **Alchemical Casting** features both have a more restrictive wording than the Sorcerer's metamagic, as they specify the restriction (emphasis mine):

> When you cast a spell **with a spell slot** [...]

If you didn't use a spell slot to cast the spell, it's not eligible to be affected by these features. As a general rule, [spells cast from items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Spells) do so without using your own slots (emphasis mine):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, **doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots**,  and requires no components, **unless the item's description says otherwise**.

If you had a magic item which explicitly let you cast a certain spell using your own spell slots, then a spell cast in that way should qualify for these effects; but I can't think of any such items off the top of my head, and they would be the exception rather than the rule.